# iOS - Grand Central Dispatch getting value from block in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, return-value, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using below code to download some data from the web. Am I right that I need to retain the data like I have done? Also the NSLog statement from inside the block shows that the array has been populated, but when I run the NSLog outside the block the arrays show as `(null)`. How would I save the data outside dispatch_async method?

```
    __block NSArray *downloadedCareerIds;
    __block NSArray *diskCareerIds;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        /* Download stuff */

        downloadedCareerIds = [[CareersParser idsFrom:@"web"] retain];
        diskCareerIds = [[CareersParser idsFrom:@"disk"] retain];

        DLog(@"downloadedCareerIds: %@", downloadedCareerIds);

        DLog(@"diskCareerIds: %@", diskCareerIds);

    });


    DLog(@"downloadedCareerIds: %@", downloadedCareerIds);

    DLog(@"diskCareerIds: %@", diskCareerIds);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch_async` is a non blocking method so it will return immediately. So when the `DLog` statements outside the block are called, they will mostly not have been set. Hence you don't see the values you get from the internal log statements.

If you want to act on the data within the same method, you will have to either send a blocking `dispatch_sync` which is pointless or you can call the methods within the block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    ....

    [self doStuffWithTheArrays];
});
```

Once the block is executed the objects will be available provided they are instance variables or you will lose the references.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the `-doStuffWithTheArrays` method needs to be declared in the interface file when I access the method in the same class? Blocks can not see own defined methods?

Answer (score 4):

The idea of dispatch_async is that you give it a block of code to execute asynchronously, therefore giving up any control of when that code gets executed.  The call to dispatch_async returns once the block has been enqueued, NOT once the block has finished executing (hence async).  Therefore, the log statements inside of the block you're passing to dispatch_async will get executed, almost always, after the log statements below your call to dispatch_async.